# How can I force re-layout of UITableViewCell when UIWebView finished loading?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, uiwebview

I have a table view where each cell contains a `UIWebView` and the height of web view dictates the height of the cell. The table view uses `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

```
class TitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var webViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.delegate = self
    }

    func configure(content: String?) {
        if let contentHTML = content {
            let html = ("<body style=\"font-family: '-apple-system'; font-size: 16; font-weight: bold; line-height: 135%; overflow-wrap: break-word\"><style>a{text-decoration: none; color: #d64a32;}img{max-width:100%; height: auto; margin: 12px 0px;}iframe{max-width:100%; height: auto;}</style><p style=\" text-align: left\">\(contentHTML)</p></body>")
            webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }   
} 
extension TitleTableViewCell: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        webViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

When I push this screen, the height of cells is the height I defined in `estimatedRowHeight` but it is not expanded to full height until I pop and push the screen again. 
How can I force expanding cells as soon as the webview has finished loading?

Answer (score 1):

You should make a delegate which invokes the table view's controller. You should set this delegate to `self` in `cellForRowAt` and reload the cell for the index path referenced in the delegate's function, `cellWebViewDidFinishLoad`.

**Delegates.swift**

```
protocol TitleCellDelegate: class {
    func cellWebViewDidFinishLoad(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

**TitleTableViewCell.swift**

```
class TitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: TitleCellDelegate?
    fileprivate var indexPath: IndexPath!

    func configure(content: String?, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        [...]

        self.indexPath = indexPath
    }   
} 

extension TitleTableViewCell: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        webViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        layoutIfNeeded()
        delegate?.cellWebViewDidFinishLoad(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: better if you pass with the indexPath the new heigth